# Replacing text in python3.9

Tags: python

I have been recently trying to make a program that replaces the text in python to make cipher , I am new to python please help when I tried to make print(a.replace('a','b').replace('b','a')); it replaces the text 'b' and change it to 'a' please help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and follow the [tour]. It's impossible to understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Take a look at [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah thats correct. lets say your example string is "aaabbbcccdddeeefff"

it would first replace all a's with b's so your string becomes this: "bbbbbbcccdddeeefff"

then you replace all b's with a's => "aaaaaacccdddeeefff"

so you essencially replaced all b's with a's

example:

```py
text = "aaabbbcccdddeeefff"
result = ""
replace_map = { # dict used for "replacing" the characters
  "a": "b", # a becomes b
  "b": "a" # b becomes a
}

for ch in text: # loop over each character in the input string
  if ch in replace_map: # if the character is in the dict replace it
    result += replace_map[ch];
  else:
    result += ch # otherwise just append it without doing anything

print(text) # print the input text
print(result) # print the result text
```

Comment: is there a way to make this example you made from "aaabbbcccdddeeefff" to"bbbaaacccdddeeefff"

Comment: yep, I added an example to my answer

Comment: thank you sorry I am new to programming